# Show <div> only if prop is defined in array

Tags: reactjs

I only want to show the `<div>` if `tax: true` in any of the `cartItem`'s. `tax` is a prop inside of `productDetails` which comes from `cartItem`:

[image]

```
    const Content = (props) => { 

    let cartItem = props.cartItem;

        {cartItem.indexOf(props.productDetails?.tax) > -1 && (
            <div>
                Show if Tax
            </div>
          )}

    };
    export default Content;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Cart Item is an array so you will have multiple cartItems there** need to loop each and display div for all cartItems which hax a tax

   ```
   const Content = (props) => { 
    let cartItem = props.cartItem;
    return (
    {cartItem.filter(p=>p?.tax).map(d => (
           <div>
               Show if Tax
           </div>
         )))}
    };
    export default Content;
   ```
2. f you need to show div if any of the cartItem have a tax

   ```
   const Content = (props) => { 

     let cartItem = props.cartItem;
     return (
     {cartItem.findIndex(p=>p?.productDetails?.tax) !== -1 ?
        <div>
            Show if Tax
        </div>
     : <></> )}
   };
    export default Content
   ```

;

Comment: #2 is what I need but it doesn't show when any of the items have tax:true in the cartItem array. Is this because tax is found inside of productDetails and not directly from the cartItem? Should your solution be p=>p?.productDetails?.tax?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: The div still didn't show when I did p?.productDetails?.tax. I think we need to change .length to check is true or false instead since the prop is always there

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the code you provided is checking if the value of `props.productDetails.tax` exists in the cartItem array. However, if you want to show the `<div>` only if `tax: true` in any of the `cartItem productDetails`, you need to check the tax value of each `productDetails` object in the `cartItem` array.

You can do this using the `Array.some()` method, which returns true if at least one element in the array satisfies the condition specified in the callback function.

```
const Content = (props) => {
  let cartItem = props.cartItem;

  if (cartItem.some((item) => item.productDetails?.tax === true)) {
    return (
      <div>
        Show if Tax
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};

export default Content;
```

If you're still confused then I want you to provide the data of props and productDetails